# How do I split a key in hashes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, key-value

I want to break the key as I want to compare their values. Below 63 represents id, rest is time.

```
[63, Thu, 14 Jul 2016 09:01:14 UTC +00:00]=>3.0
```

Comment: What should be the expected output ?

Comment: I want to fetch the id and time from the key

Comment: @AasishSharma compare to what, can you give us more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby can extract all parts of key and value for you if you provide enough block parameters.

I assume your hash is stored in a variable named `hash`.

If you specify only two parameters, Ruby will put the key in the first one and the value in the second one.

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key # prints [63, Thu, 14 Jul 2016 09:01:14 UTC +00:00]
  puts value # prints 3.0
end
```

But Ruby can also expand the key for you. In your key, you have 2 values. So you need to give 2 block parameters, in braces:

```
hash.each do |(id, time), value|
  puts id # prints 63
  puts time # prints Thu, 14 Jul 2016 09:01:14 UTC +00:00
  puts value # prints 3.0
end
```

You can give the block parameters any names you like.

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, they are *highly unrecommended*, because if the question's author understood the code being posted, he would probably have come up with a similar solution of his own, and thus wouldn't be asking for help. Please understand that the nature of a Q&A site such as SO is inherently that of a *learning and teaching* community, rather than that of a crowd-sourcing one, and thus, an actual *answer* is far more valuable than just *code*.

Comment: I had to go so I posted this quick snippet. Will edit now.